# Deployment of Visual Studio projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

My question is simple, how do i deploy or publish my Visual Studio project that is linked with an external library specifically, the OpenCV library. And that it can be run in other computers

Comment: Are you using a `dll` of `OpenCV`?

Comment: Yes I am using a dll of opencv, should i just copy it to the folder where the exe of the project is located? I actually want it to run in other computers

Comment: Don't forget that you also need to ship the Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable runtime along with your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DLL`s are very carefully to handle with. As you mentioned in your comment, you should place it right next to your executable.

Windows searches in several locations for your `DLL`s. In System folders and so on and in the folder where your executable is placed. For portability to other systems and to avoid, that windows uses the wrong `DLL`, you should place it along side your executable.

This [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) states:

> The standard DLL search order used by the system depends on whether safe DLL search mode is enabled or disabled. Safe DLL search mode places the user's current directory later in the search order.

...

> If SafeDllSearchMode is enabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
>      2.The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 2. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 3. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The current directory.
> 5. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.
>
> If SafeDllSearchMode is disabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
>      The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

If it is possible you should define your `DLL` with an absolute path. Just for completeness. Also from the link:

> A system can contain multiple versions of the same dynamic-link library (DLL). Applications can control the location from which a DLL is loaded by specifying a full path or using another mechanism such as a manifest.

As mentioned in the comments, you have to include the MVS run-time `DLL`s as well.

Comment: I tried to copy the exe file and the dlls of opencv and also the other dlls it asks inside a folder. and copied it to another computer. It run but I'm getting this error [link](https://ibb.co/gr9rrHR)

Comment: It occurs to me, that this isn't a problem related to a `dll`-load. Search in the given file, for the given line and investigate what is wrong there.